# How to bind Spring project with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, spring-tool-suite

how to bind Spring project with SonarQube, I have used STS(Spring Tool Suite) IDE for my project development. I started SonarQube in http://localhost:9000, and created the project under 'Projects' menu on sonarqube home page, but I can not link the projects with sonarqube and STS IDE.
How to resolve this?

Comment: Since I think this is a very specific question around sonar, I would add a tag for that to get those people on board here. Doesn't look very Eclipse or STS specific...

Answer (score 1):

When you have the SonarLint plugin for Eclipse installed, you can create a project on your Sonar-Server and bind your local project from STS to this particular project on the server.
Just right-click on your project, select SonarLint and then Bind to a SonarQubeProject.
There you can select a server and specify the project you want to bind it to on the server.

Although your question is not specified at all, i hope it helped you.